# Prove $\sin|x^2+y|$ is not continuously differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity, continuous-variables

> Let $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}, F(x,y)=\sin |x^2+y|$.
>
> a) Prove that $F(x,y)$ is not continuously differentiable at $(0,0)$.
>
> b) Is $F$ differentiable at $(0,0)$?

I can do part b):
If $F$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ then $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}(0,0)$ must exist. However,
$$
\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}(0,0)=\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\dfrac{F(0,y)-F(0,0)}{y}=\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\dfrac{\sin|y|}{y}
$$ does not exist! So $F$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.\

I'm stuck at part a): 
I have been trying to show that
$$
\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}(0,b)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin|x^2+b|-\sin|b|}{x}
$$ or that
$$
\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}(a,0)=\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\dfrac{\sin|a^2+y|-\sin|a^2|}{y}
$$ does not exist .
But I don't know how to proceed. Could someone help me or have other ways to deal with the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Continuously differentiable at a point is not meaningful.

Comment: @geetha290krm Why not? If $F$ is continuous differentiable at $(0,0)$ then $F$ belongs to $C^1$ at $(0,0)$.

Comment: $b)\implies a)$

Comment: We can talk about  $f$ being  continuously differentiable on an open set , but not at a point. Besides, you have proved that $F$ is not even differentiable at $(0,0)$ so there is nothing to do in part a).